# BadTokenException by DialogFragment onStart

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I went through 100 posts about BadTokenException but it seems that each time there is another reasson why this is happening, in my case I am seeing this stack trace some times (does not happen always/don't know how to reproduce):

```
Caused by android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window – token android.os.BinderProxy@2a5a564 is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:602)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:98)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(SourceFile:434)
at com.mycompany.myapp.ui.about.WhatsNewDialog.onStart(SourceFile:89)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(SourceFile:2372)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1467)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1759)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1827)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:797)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2596)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2383)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:2338)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:2245)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(SourceFile:3248)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(SourceFile:3212)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(SourceFile:217)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(SourceFile:509)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:498)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:171)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3268)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5560)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

As I understand the trace, the exception happens directly in the onStart of the DialogFragment, that's the only line of code of the app itself being shown, at that line only super.onStart() is called, nothing more is present in this method, so this is really confusing, do you understand it?
Would in this case also be the solution using "activity.isFinishing()"? In the stacktrace I don't even see the line where I call new WhatsNewDialog().show(), so this may be really happening while resuming the Dialog somehow, any tips are welcome.

Comment: Is it possible to post some code?

Answer (score 0):

It actually gives you the error.

You are launching a DialogFragment from a inactive activity. So either you are finishing that activity as soon as you launch the dialogFragment or you are launching it with a dead or memory leaked version of an activity.

If you need more help then this, I need to see where you launch it from, and the code following to see if you are destroying the parent.

Comment: I am not destroying nothing manually, the dialog is being called in onResume of an Activity.

Comment: I need to see code to help you any further @David are you willing to share your code to get it resolved? if not, I cannot help you.